# How to get an Item's Lifetime in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

I would like to show Menu items on page, based on their valid from & to dates. But before that, wanted to test the output. The `_Valid to` date is set to `3/17/2016 12:00 AM` for the 'About us' item.

The output is `About us--`.
What is the right way to get the Valid from & to dates.

```
protected void rpMenu_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  var mainItem = (Item)e.Item.DataItem;                

  if (mainItem != null)
  {
    Response.Write(mainItem.Name + "-" + mainItem.Fields["Valid to"] + "-");

    //this one did not work too
    Response.Write(mainItem.Name + "-" + mainItem.Fields["_Valid to"] + "-");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use next constants for getting ValidTo and ValidFrom fields

`mainItem.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.ValidFrom]` and `mainItem.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.ValidTo]`

These constants are from `Sitecore.Kernel assembly`.